# Async function does exit with code 0 even if error was thrown

Tags: node.js, async-await, throw, error-code

Does anyone know how to make an async function exit with an non-zero exit code if an error was thrown?

If a sync function throws an error, the NodeJS script exits with an error code:

*sync.js*:

```js
'use strict'

const main = function () {
    throw Error('Something failed hard')
}

main()
```

```sh
$ node sync.js
> ... Error: Something failed hard ...

$ echo $?
> 130
```

But if I do the same with an async function, the error code is always `0`:

*async.js*:

```js
'use strict'

const main = async function () {
    throw Error('Something failed hard')
}

main()
```

```sh
$ node async.js
> ... UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Something failed hard ...

$ echo $?
> 0
```

The closest thing I was able to do was:

*async2.js*:

```js
'use strict'

const main = async function () {
    process.exit(1)
    throw Error('Something failed hard')
}

main()
```

```sh
$ node async2.js

$ echo $?
> 1
```

But then the error won't be thrown as the script has already exited :-P

I'm using Node 12.8.3.

I guess that the script doesn't wait until the promise was rejected before it exits. But I have no idea how to make the async function wait as I can't use `await` outside of a function :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that you don't need to use `process.exit(<code>)` but you can set the exit code that will be used when the script exits beforehand with `process.exitCode = <code>`.

So this works:

*async3.js*:

```js
'use strict'

const main = async function () {
    process.exitCode = 1
    throw Error('Something failed hard')
}

main()
```

```sh
$ node async3.js
> ... UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Something failed hard ...

$ echo $?
> 1
```

Thanks everyone for being my rubber duck!

Comment: Can anyone explain though why node works like this?

Comment: It seems to be a bad practice to call process.exit() because there may be pending asynchronous tasks that still need to be completed. More details can be found here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason the status code when using an async function is 0 is that throwing in an async method raises a Promise rejection but it doesn't throw in the strict sense. The error is wrapped inside a Promise rejection and that is probably considered to be regular execution, which makes sense after all, hence the success status code.

Comment: Your theory sounds coherent, but do you have any source that backs it?

Comment: I believe this article was one of the sources I based my answer from: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/throw-async/#how-to-throw-errors-from-async-functions-in-javascript-testing-exceptions